# Can you pass a delegate Func<> parameter dynamically named? method("FuncdelegateNameOfMethod")

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

You can pass in a method into another method that's takes Func<>. But can you pass that in as a dynamically named string so you can what method is passed in on the fly?

Answer (score 2):

> You can pass in a method into another method that's takes `Func<>`.

It's worth separating out the "passing a value" from "creating the value in the first place". When you write code such as:

```
InvokeSomeDelegate(MethodToInvoke);
```

That's performing a *method group conversion* to create a delegate instance. In other words, it's equivalent to:

```
Func<Whatever> func = MethodToInvoke;
InvokeSomeDelegate(func);
```

So really the question isn't so much about how you can pass a string into the method, as how to create a delegate based on a string. That in turn leads to the question of what kind of method, what type it's in etc.

The framework method you want to use is [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=netframework-4.8), but exactly how you use that will depend on the context, so that you can find the right `MethodInfo` with reflection. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        InvokeFunc("Double");
        InvokeFunc("Quadruple");
        InvokeFunc("AddOne");
    }

    static void InvokeFunc(string name)
    {
        // Note that in our case they're all private static methods. You'd
        // need to adjust the binding flags if that's not the case. If you
        // need to worry about multiple overloads, that makes it harder too.
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Test)
            .GetMethod(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        // TODO: Validate that you've got a method
        var func = (Func<int, int>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Func<int, int>), // Delegate type to create                                                            
            null, // Target of method call; null because ours are static
            method); // Method to create a delegate for
        var result = func(10);
        Console.WriteLine($"{name}(10) => {result}");
    }

    static int Double(int x) => x * 2;
    static int Quadruple(int x) => x * 4;
    static int AddOne(int x) => x + 1;
}
```

Note that all the reflection to find the method and then create the delegate is relatively slow. If you're doing this with any significant performance constraints, you may want to add caching.

Comment: Yepp! Creating a MethodInfo object based on the method name and then creating a delegate of type Func<,> based on the MethodInfo, depending on the signature required is the way to go.